# Are overhead (tennis-like) serves allowed in squash?

Tags: rules, squash, serve

When I watch others play squash (in-real-life or on youtube) I never see them serve what I refer to as over-the-head, much like the serves in tennis. I wonder if there is a reason for that. Is it so that the particular style of serving is not allowed, or just not desirable for some reason?

I personally find that I generate much more power on the serve if I go for an overhead serve and think that it could be useful in some occasions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answer: **YES**

The serve, in squash is called an Hard Serve or Power Serve. But not many experienced players do it for the sole purpose that you are leaving yourself in a bad position for the return.

[image]

If you look at the picture above, You will see that you (obviously) need to bring your racket up in the air and then follow through with your swing, pushing your racket down. This does create a fast serve which makes it difficult for a novice player to return. But if you're playing an experienced player who knows how to return a fast paced ball, that player will most likely return the ball before you can recover from your "overhand" swing follow through. This is why most people serve underhand so that their racket will be in position when the opponent returns the ball.

To sum up pros and cons...

- PROS

  - If you are playing a novice player, this is a great serve because of the pace (speed) of the ball.
  - It is good to use this serve if your opponent getting used to you using a normal underhand server.
- CONS

  - Any experienced player will be able to return this serve and most likely beat you because you have not recovered from the long follow through that this serve requires.

Comment: Great, thanks! But isn't that also a matter of where you aim the ball with the power serve?

Comment: You can aim the ball at different locations on the wall to result in a different rebound that the opponent is not expecting. This results in the opponent having to change his/her stance and might end up with him/her committing an error. But this applies with **all** squash serves, which is why I didn't add it in the answer to this question on a specific serve.

Comment: I was referring to the fact that it would be harder for the opponent to react in time, since the serve comes at a harder pace. But I guess it applies to serving in general. I just don't understand how people get up proper speed with underhand serves... :/

Comment: My answer: They're good haha. Just think if those people served overhand. It would be even faster.